# C++ приложение, запускаемое на любом дистрибутиве linux

Tags: c++, linux

Возможно ли скомпилировать приложение под linux (x64), имеющее зависимости, которое можно запустить на любом дистрибутиве linux без дополнительных действий со стороны сисадмина (компиляция, установка библиотек...)? Пробовал поставлять со всеми библиотеками и запускать с ld_library_path. Работает, но только на одинаковых дистрибутивах, иначе возникает ошибка связанная со стандартной библиотекой(не помню уже). Подумывал в сторону Docker, но нужно опять же его устанавливать. Возможно ли вообще сделать то что я пишу и какой разумный компромиcс если нет?

Comment: На любом — вряд ли. У вас могут оказаться даже процессоры разные. А в чём проблема скомпилироваться на целевой системе?

Comment: Нет, это сделать не реально. Ближе всего будет статически слинкованный исполняемый файл а-ля go-lang. Его вполне можно будет использовать не нескольких вариантах линукса. Но вообще отдельный варинт - отдельная сборка.

Comment: в Питоне с Си расширениями может использоваться [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) — расширение компилируется на древней версии glibc, использует только [избранные внешние библиотеки](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/#id40), использует переносимое ABI ядра — вы можете похожий подход попробовать (x86-64, i686).

Comment: Подход в manylinux конечно интересный, но реальное приложение действительно нужно компилировать для каждого дистрибутива. Спасибо что помогли в этом разобраться!

Comment: Например оракл поставляется для linux в виде объектного файла, который линкуется все равно на целевой платформе. Боюсь единственный путь - статическая линковка, что бы не зависеть ни от каких местных библиотек, но размер файла будет конечно большим

Comment: @LuckyUser расширения manylinux компилируются один раз, а затем в бинарном виде распространяются—в этом весь смысл их: не нужно под каждый дистрибутив собирать.

Comment: @jfs, я это понял. Но там очень жесткие ограничения в зависимостях. Такой подход хорош для написания переносимого модуля для того же питона, но в реальном приложении очень сложно них вложиться. Ведь даже если использовать все статические библиотеки в приложении, они все равно могут иметь свои зависимости(поправьте если не прав).

Comment: Я сейчас компилирую в старом (7ом) Дебиане.  LD_LIBRARY_PATH не обязательно в большом числе случаев

Answer (score 1):

> возникает ошибка связанная со стандартной библиотекой(не помню уже)

Очень много информации... :-) Подозреваю, что дело тут не в разных дистрибутивах, а в разных версиях этой библиотеки на разных дистрибутивах. Проще:

Вы разработали и собрали свою программу на хосте, где была установлена библиотека libaaa.7.so.

Вы перенесли ELF на другой хост, где установлена libaaa.6.so.

При запуске программы выдастся сообщение о том, что загрузчик не может найти седьмую версию этой библиотеки. И эта ситуация возможна на одном дистрибудитве, если на одном хосте установлена последняя версия. а на друго - более старая.

Бороться с этим можно двумя способами:

1. Инсталлировать Вашу программу с помощью стандартного Linux механизма - пакетов.  rpm или deb или и то и другое. Тогда требуемый апгрейд выполнится автоматически.
2. Попробовать обмануть загрузчик, выполнив команду вроде этой:

   sudo ln -s libaaa.6.so libaaa.7.so

Но это рисковано...

А вот это:

> реальное приложение действительно нужно компилировать для каждого
>   дистрибутива

типичный видовозный подход - одна версия для семёрки, другая для.... Не повторяйте этой ошибки!